# Fuelux datepicker how do I initialise it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, fuelux

I'm trying to use the [fuelux datepicker](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#datepicker) and can't seem to even initialise it properly! Any help would be most appreciated. I've based it on the examples here: https://gist.github.com/vernak2539/9980566

Header of page:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.4.0/css/fuelux.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fuelux">
  <div class="datepicker dropdown" id="myDatepicker">
    <div class="input-append">
        <div class="dropdown-menu"></div>
        <input type="text" class="span2" value="" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Before my JS:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.4.0/js/fuelux.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myDatepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Also tried in a fiddle and thought it would be sufficient but it isn't working:
http://jsfiddle.net/z2rpos9g/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it looks like the markup is more important

check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/4eg2qc42/)

also you should add

```
fuelux
```

class to the div which has datepicker.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply.
Regarding the markup - this is what I can't understand, do I really need to add all the markup for each datepicker on the page?! Look at this fiddle that shows a date picker for a previous version, no markup in sight! http://jsfiddle.net/Cg93W/3/

Also, I can't see why I'd need to add fuelux to both the div with the date picker and the outer div also - if that's what you're suggesting. I'll give it a shot though.

Thanks again!

Comment: We switched to a markup declarative architecture in line with Bootstrap 3. This allows for a simpler API, easier internationalization among other things. Feeding a markup template into each control and making architecture closer to pseudo-web-components may be on the roadmap. We recognize there are problems with copying & pasting lots of markup, etc. The .fuelux wrapper class is present, so you can have non-fuelux datepicker classes.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies. It could just be me rushing through the docs, but it didn't seem immediately obvious that I needed to add the markup.